# Is there any better MACRO to get constant power value of 2^n (1 << n)

Tags: c, macros

I needed to get power of some constants which are power of two .
To optimize run-time, I adopt MACRO to get these power during compilation stage.
(8 -> 3,  16 -> 4,  32 -> 5 ... etc.)

From the book "hacker's delight", I found a function useful to find a power of 2^n, which is Counting 1-Bits. The problem becomes counting the 1-bits of (2^n - 1). 
For example, 2^8 - 1 is 255 which has 8 1-bits and 8 is the power of 256.
The following are the expressions to count a 1-bits of a 32-bit variable.

```
x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);  
x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);  
x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);  
x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);  
x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) + ((x >>16) & 0x0000FFFF);
```

So I expand these five expression in a MACRO to get the power of a constant value N, which is power of two. It's useful but not to say very tedious.

```
N is an power of two constant value, and let x = N - 1

#define mGET_POWER_OF_2S_VALUE(x)   ( (((((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F)) & 0x00FF00FF) + ((((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F)) >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF)) & 0x0000FFFF) + ((((((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F)) & 0x00FF00FF) + ((((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((( ((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((((x) & 0x55555555) + (((x) >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333)) >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F)) >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF)) >>16) & 0x0000FFFF) )
```

p.s. My platform is embedded system and there is NO any C standard library to use during coding.

Comment: there are many solutions [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) and you can make the function [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) to get the value at the compile time

Comment: By "get the power of X" you mean "get the base-2 logarithm of X"

Comment: Yes, I already had a  MACRO of "get the base-2 logarithm of X" as mentioned in my question. I just wonder if there is more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

With a handful of helper macros, you can make your macro less monstrous:

```
#define x1(x)   (x & 0x55555555) + (x>> 1 & 0x55555555)
#define x2(x)   (x & 0x33333333) + (x>> 2 & 0x33333333)
#define x3(x)   (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + (x>> 4 & 0x0F0F0F0F)
#define x4(x)   (x & 0x00FF00FF) + (x>> 8 & 0x00FF00FF)
#define x5(x)   (x & 0x0000FFFF) + (x>>16 & 0x0000FFFF)
#define mGET_POWER_OF_2S_VALUE(x)   x5(x4(x3(x2(x1(x)))))
```

---

Another way (also computable at compile time for a given N = 2<sup>0..32</sup>) is this:

```
#define P(i)  1U<<i?i:
#define LB(N) N&P(0)N&P(1)N&P(2)N&P(3)N&P(4)N&P(5)N&P(6)N&P(7)N&P(8)N&P(9)\
              N&P(10)N&P(11)N&P(12)N&P(13)N&P(14)N&P(15)N&P(16)N&P(17)N&P(18)\
              N&P(19)N&P(20)N&P(21)N&P(22)N&P(23)N&P(24)N&P(25)N&P(26)N&P(27)\
              N&P(28)N&P(29)N&P(30)N&P(31)32
```

By the way, this macro `LB()` also yields the index of the lowest set bit for values 1..0x1FFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are constants, I don't understand why you need to compute this at run-time at all. It would probably be best to use the simplest possible expression (perhaps even using `log()`) and see what the compiler does, it's quite likely to figure it out at compile-time.

Comment: My resource is very limited.  My platform is embedded system, so these is NO any C standard library such as math.h. These power of two constants may be changed in the future, therefore lots of power values I need will also be changed correspondingly before run-time.